# Deserialize JSON object on windows phone

Tags: json, api, serialization, windows-phone-7.1

I need help with this:

My JSON (It's from Diablo 3 API):

```
{
   "name":"Exsanguinating Chopsword of Assault",
   "icon":"mightyweapon1h_202",
   "displayColor":"blue",
   "tooltipParams":"item-data/COGHsoAIEgcIBBXIGEoRHYQRdRUdnWyzFB2qXu51MA04kwNAAFAKYJMD",
   "requiredLevel":60,
   "itemLevel":61,
   "bonusAffixes":0,
   "dps":{
       "min":206.69999241828918,
       "max":206.69999241828918
    }
}
```

It's not complete JSON, but I'm trying to parse only this piece because I'm learning about it.

I know how to get the the strings name,icon,displayColor..... but I don't know how to get the DPS.

My model class is:

```
namespace Diablo_III_Profile
{
[DataContract]
public class ItemInformation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    [DataMember]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("name");
            }
        }
    }
    //others strings and ints here

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

What is the "format" of DPS to put in my model class?

To read the strings I'm using this:

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 ItemInformation data = (ItemInformation)Deserialize(ms, typeof(ItemInformation));
 MessageBox.Show(data.name);
```

Should be the same to DPS?

EDIT:

I DID IT! Dunno if is the best way but....

Inside my model class I put

```
public class DPS
    {
        public float min { get; set; }
        public float max { get; set; }
    }

    private DPS _dps;

    [DataMember]
    public DPS dps
    {
        get
        {
            return _dps;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _dps)
            {
                _dps = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("dps");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome @adelmo-pereira that you fixed your problem, but could you answer your question with your solution please? It will let other people find the solution easier, it's the way we want things on Sack Overflow. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel ! Its my first time using Stackoverflow to ask something.

Comment: It's cool, welcome here :) Hope you get all you're looking for, and also help some other people :)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good, that is exactly what I was trying to reply with. This way you can reuse the DPS wherever you want and JSON parser should deserialize it properly to the "ItemInformation" with proper values for DPS min and max. I have used the same methodology to populate objects and child objects.

You can also use JSON.Net for Serializing to JSON and Deserializing JSON objects.

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I DID IT! Dunno if is the best way but....

Inside my model class I put

```
public class DPS  
 {  
     public float min { get; set; }  
     public float max { get; set; }  
 }  

private DPS _dps;  

[DataMember]  
public DPS dps  
{  
    get  
    {  
        return _dps;  
    }  
    set  
    {  
        if (value != _dps)  
        {  
            _dps = value;  
            NotifyPropertyChanged("dps");  
        }  
    }  
}
```